# Query to get student name and count of students is not working using this code.please help someone

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT student_name, COUNT(*)c
FROM  btl_english 
GROUP BY student_name 
HAVING count > 1
```

## 1054 - Unknown column 'count' in 'having clause'

Comment: What means `not working`?

Comment: You need to share your table structure and some sample data, and provide more detail about the error.

Consider using sqlfiddle.com for this.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use the alias name in your HAVING clause. Try this:

```
SELECT student_name, COUNT(*) c 
FROM  btl_english 
GROUP BY student_name 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: That depends on the database.  Many SQL engines do allow aliases in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff:- Yes, but I suspect that this might be the reason.(*Honestly I guessed it*)

Comment: Since no DBMS is tagged, ANSI SQL is expected. And ANSI SQL does not allow column aliases in the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logical query processing
order of the six main query clauses:

> 1. FROM
> 2. WHERE
> 3. GROUP BY
> 4. HAVING
> 5. SELECT
> 6. ORDER BY

**For you Referance:**

<kbd>[Below is the Logical query processing flow chart for each clause :Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you)</kbd>

[image]

The `Select` list is parsed only after the `Having` clause. At time Having clause parsing, the parser doesn't have select list. So you will get the following error

> Invalid column name 'c'.

Means the parser try to finds the column c in the table(not the select list), which is not found.

That's why you can't get results.

use `count(*)` instead of alias in your case